# C how to store words in a char pointer from the user input

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *read[100];
    char *ch, *back;
    int i;

    ch = read;

    printf("Enter a sentence and get it reversed: ");
    while (getchar() != '\n') {
        *ch = getchar();
        ch++;
    }

    for (back = ch; back != read; back--) {
        printf("%s",*back);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my code. Does is it possible to store Strings in a Array or a pointer. This language is old. For exampel if the user wrote void and null the output should be null and void. And i tries this with a pointer to char array and want to just print the word backwords and it dosen't do anything. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Try reading the input using scanf() or gets().Still, I don't think your code would do what you want it to.

Comment: Your problem starts with the declaration of `read` as an array of pointers, continues with you assigning `read` (which decays to a pointer, and becomes a pointer to a pointer to `char`) to `ch` which is a pointer to `char`. I'm sure een a beginner lie you should be able to see that there is a difference between a pointer to pointer to `char`, and a pointer to `char`

Comment: The language is old?

Comment: em... you need to know what `read`'s type is first.

Answer (score 4):

Three problems:

1. `char *read[100];` isn't array of `char`s. It is an array of pointers to `char`. Change that to `char read[100];` to get an array of `char`s of size 100.
2. `printf("%s",*back);` is wrong as `*back` is a `char` but `℅s` expects a `char*`. Change it to `printf("%c",*back);`.
3. This `for (back = ch; back != read; back--) {` should be `for (back = ch - 1; back >= read; back--) {`. Otherwise, you'll be reading an uninitialized memory location in the first iteration of the loop.

Now that your code is vulnerable to a buffer overflow, i.e, when more than 100 characters are inputted, anything could be the result as your program will read and write from invalid memory locations invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) if your system (e.g. a POSIX one) has it. Otherwise, declare a large enough line buffer (e.g. `char linebuf[200];`) and use [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html)

Then, you might parse the string (that is, your line buffer). You could use functions from `<ctype.h>` like [isalpha(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html), or perhaps use [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) (with e.g. a control string containing `%70[A-Za-z]`...)

Things would become more complex if you want to parse [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) strings (since non-latin letters -like the Russian [yery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yery) e.g. `Ы`- have multi-byte encoding). Then use some [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) library like [libunistring](http://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/)

Answer (score 2):

Strings in C don't have all the fancy stuff that Strings in Java or C#/.Net have. C strings are basically array's of char which are ended by a '\0' character. So when a function is doing operations on C string it starts reading characters at the memory location as specified by your char* pointer and goes on reading until it finds a '\0' character in the string. If it doesn't find a '\0' character it will go on reading characters until it hits an error because it's trying to read memory in a non assigned/allocated memory address. ps. You cannot assign void as value as it is a type.